# internal CSS snap scrolling aligning with pixels

Tags: css, scrollbar

first off I'm a total noob and I know i go about things the wrong way.
Ok, so here's what I'm trying to do:
I have a website that's basically just one image that's super long. In said picture I have different places that I want the snap scrolling to stop at. So basically what I'm thinking is that I have a y mandatory scroll snap where it snaps according to set pixels or percentages. Instead of containers. I've been trying to google and bend the results I found into what I need to no avail.

I want internal CSS because it's easier for me :)

Do you have an idea of what I should do?
Do you understand the question? If not I'll try to explain more.

```
.scroller {
  
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;

 
  scroll-snap-destination: 0% 100%;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
}

.page {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Comment: I just want to add that i dont know anything about CSS. This is my first time diddeling in it

Comment: Can you create a snippet so we can try and see what your problem is?